# How do I put my php script on my WAN IP address as it's currently on my local host?

Tags: php, sql, reactjs, debugging

I currently can successfully enter user inputted information to the DB using MySQL with a React.js frontend.

I'm using MAMP and my php script lives inside the `htdocs` folder.

I have a php script that runs on local host but now I'd like to expose it.  I've already gained access to my WAN IP address via http://www.whatismyip.com/.  How do I put my php script on my WAN IP address as it's currently on my local host so I can expose it to the world?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to expose your script publicly from your own private network. In that case, you need to configure something called "port forwarding" on your router.

The concept is pretty simple: if someone attempts to visit your public-facing IP address, that traffic passes through your router. Your router has no idea what to do with this traffic, so it simply drops it by default. Port forwarding tells your router "if you receive traffic on this specific port of yours, then direct it to this other port on this other device". For a typical web interface, you would want to forward the router's port `80` for HTTP and `443` for HTTPS traffic, to the appropriate equivalents for your local web server's configuration.

Common ways to view your router's admin interface would be the IP addresses `192.168.0.1` or `10.0.0.1`. Other possibilities may exist, which (for most residential users, anyway) can usually be listed as a "default gateway" entry when listing your network settings from the command line. Specific instructions for setting up port forwarding on your router will depend largely on the specific router you own, and are thus beyond the scope of this question. You should be able to find the settings pretty quickly just by digging around through the admin interface, however.